# OptaPlanner: does the Drools null-safe dereference operator not work in OptaPlanner DRL rules?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

According to the [Drools v7.46.0.Final documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.46.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drl-operators-ref_drl-rules)  for the null-safe dereferencing operator `!.`, expressions of the form

`Type( $data : property!.data )`

are internally expanded/represented as:

`Type( property != null, $data : property.data )`

However, this does not seem to work in the context of OptaPlanner.

For the rule

```
Type( $data : property!.data )
```

the generated code is

```java
package some.classes;

import static location.RulesAHASH1.*;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.bendablelong.BendableLongScoreHolder;
import org.drools.modelcompiler.dsl.pattern.D;

// other imports

@org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.MaterializedLambda()
public enum LambdaExtractorAHASH2 implements org.drools.model.functions.Function1<Type, java.lang.Long> {

    INSTANCE;

    public static final String EXPRESSION_HASH = "SOME_HASH";

    @Override()
    public java.lang.Long apply(Type _this) {
        return _this.getProperty() != null && _this.getProperty().getData();
    }
}
```

and given that `data` is not a `boolean` and `apply` has a return type of `Long`, this throws an exception.

The message:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=blah/blah/blah/LambdaExtractorHASH.java, line=24, column=54
   text=bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
  first type:  boolean
  second type: java.lang.Long]

...

// generated code etc.
```

So, are we not supposed to use this notation when using Drools with OptaPlanner?  Are there other language limitations?

Update:

Pulled the optaplanner repo, switched to 8.8.x, and modified a vehicleRoutingConstriants DRL rule to use the null-safe dereference operator:

```
rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill"
    when
        $customer : Customer($prevVehicle : previousStandstill!.vehicle, previousStandstill != null, $distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)
    then
        System.out.println($prevVehicle);
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $distanceFromPreviousStandstill);
end
```

This runs as expected.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with OptaPlanner's specific flavor of Drools, so I'm curious to know if this is a language limitation (possibly documented elsewhere) or a bug. Can you update your question with the versions of the libraries you're using?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas for sure; post updated.

Comment: Not sure why I have more than one `compiler` and `core` hmmm...

Comment: JK, figured it out.  Tried to be clever and just copy-paste out of my "Project and External Dependencies" folder and trim the names, but I goofed:

`|    +--- org.kie.kogito:drools-core:1.0.0.Final`
`|    |    +--- org.drools:drools-core:7.46.0.Final`

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why that would happen, none likely to have anything to do with OptaPlanner. I suggest you upgrade to the latest OptaPlanner, which will get you the latest Drools - if the issue is still there, let's talk more.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas For completeness: OptaPlanner uses normal Drools DRL except that PropertyReactive is set to ALLOWED instead of ALWAYS (which wouldn't affect that code here). This issue sounds like a bug in Drools.

Comment: O.k., I'll have to get back to you guys once I can upgrade.  Once I'm able, I'll try this out again and post an update. @GeoffreyDeSmet

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Pulled the optaplanner repo and, on the 8.8.x branch, can confirm that the null-safe dereference works just fine.

I'll update my question and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to 8.8.x fixed the issue for me

Workaround:

replace the null dereference operator expression with what the internal representation is supposed to be, so, rather than writing this:

```
rule "name"
    when
        MyClass($subField : field!.subField)
        // more matching
    then
        // do some stuff
end
```

write this:

```
rule "name"
    when
        MyClass(field != null, $subField : field.subField)
        // more matching
    then
        // do some stuff
end
```

Comment: This issue seems to have reemerged when updating to OptaPlanner v8.21.1.Final which brings with it Drools v8.21.1.Beta